# FileObject reads input that is not in file, c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm working on this program that is supposed to read data from a file that is formatted like the following, Code#Salary. The user is supposed to give a code, the program should find that code in the file if it exists and then return the salary. However, when I run the program, I keep getting a salary that is not even one of the options.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
 int code;
 double salary;
 int name;
 ifstream inFile;

 inFile.open("/Users/rsoni613/Desktop/payroll.txt");

 if (inFile)
 {
    cout << "Enter payroll code: ";
    cin >> code;

            do
            {
                inFile >> name;
            }
            while (code != name);
            
            inFile.ignore('#');
            inFile >> salary;
            inFile.close();
            cout << "Salary: $" << salary << endl; 
        
 }
 else
 {
    cout << "File did not open, please retry.";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

---

Here are the contents of input file, payroll.txt

```
1#23400
4#17000
5#21000
6#12600
9#26700
10#18900
11#18500
13#12000
15#49000
16#56500
20#65000
21#65500
22#78200
23#71000
24#71100
25#72000
30#83000
31#84000
32#90000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double salary;
```

variable salary is of type `double`. No wonder you are getting different result.